# Backbone collection add method being fired twice

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For the following code, the `add` event bound in the view fires twice (more if you add more elements to the collection at once).

http://jsfiddle.net/radu/GnG66/

```
App = window.App || {};

var Model = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend();
App.collection = new Collection({ model: Model });

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click': function() {
            console.log('click');
            App.collection.add([{
                foo: 'foo'
            }, {
                bar: 'bar'
            }]);
        }
    },
    initialize: function() {
        App.collection.on('add', function() {
            console.log('Something has been added to the collection')
        }, this);
    }
});

$(function() {
    App.view = new View({ el: '#test' });
});​
```

If instead of adding an array to the collection, you just pass several objects as arguments (basically just remove the square brackets), the event only fires once.

Is this by design and is there a way to override this behaviour without passing `{ silent : true }` as an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `add` event is fired once for each model added.

[`Collection.add`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) can take an array of models, or a single model and some options.

In your example above, you are passing an array of two models in. Since the `add` event gets fired once for each model added, it fires twice.

When you pass in several objects, Backbone thinks the first object is a model and the second is a hash of options. That means only one model is being added, so it fires the `add` event once.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks! I assumed the models were being added as expected by checking `App.collection.models.length` but turns out that isn't a good idea and the mistake is exposed by adding more than 2 items to the collection.

Comment: So the only way around this is to pass `{ silent : true }` and then trigger the add event manually?

Comment: Why don't you want an `add` event per model? You might want to structure you app differently if you need to add two models at once and only trigger one `add` listener. Maybe those two models should really be a single one?

Comment: I'm dealing with a collection of search results, each of which is represented by a model. So I'm getting multiple search results at once (possibly loading more later), and would prefer to add everything at once.

Comment: You can add everything at once, you just deal with them one at a time in individual `add` handlers. What would backbone return in the add handler besides a single model?

Comment: I realize that's a possibility, but touching the DOM 100 times vs. only once can be a big difference in performance.

Comment: Do you need to add those models are are they replacing your entire collection? If so, have a look at `collection.fetch()` which fires a single `change` event. You can also tell fetch to add the models instead of replacing them.

Comment: If you want to batch adds so you can add things in to the dom, you do something like aggregating newly added models in an add event, and if no add event is fired for a few milliseconds, insert the newly added models all at once.

Comment: I'm with you @Radu, pass { silent: true } and after fire it manually seems like will do the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to resurrect this question from the dead, but I was having this problem too and wanted to post how I solved it. The problem with having `'add'` trigger so many times for me was because I had a complex render function in my view that was listening for `'add'`. This was causing serious performance issues.

I resolved it by creating a temporary collection using backbone's handy `collection.clone()` method on it, adding the new models to it, and then resetting the original collection with the temp collection's `models` property. The code looks like this:

```
// Create a temporary copy of searchResults
var temp = App.searchResults.clone();

// Add the new results
temp.add(newResults.models);

// Copy the new data over the old data
App.searchResults.reset(temp.models);

// Added this since reset triggers 'reset' and my view is listening for 'change add remove'
this.get('filtered_flights').trigger('change');
```

This sets off only ONE `'change'` event instead of several `'add'` events.

Comment: Whoa, this just got an upvote! Anyway, after a few more years with Backbone, I've since learned that the **better** way of doing this is to just write views that can handle large batches of add/remove events at once. `_.debounce`, `_.throttle`, and `_.defer` are useful, or storing updates in a list that gets processed for rendering later.